How to connect an c# Web-API, which runs on a IONOS windows Server, to a IONOS mySQL database
I want to run a c# Web-API on my IONOS Windows Server. The Web-API should deal with inquiries from Desktop App's and a Webpage. In order to provide this service I want to connect my API with a mySQL Database.
Futhermore I using the following Production Connection-String (I have of course exchanged security-relevant data) :
"Production": "server=db1234567890.hosting-data.io;port=3306;database=dbs12345678;username=dbu123456;password=MySecurePassword"

This Page helped me to find out that IONOS has secured their Database Servers for external access:
https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/123946/kein-externes-zugriff-auf-die-mysql-datenbank-bei-ionos (Last Access: 28.09.24)
The Problem is that on the one hand IONOS has secured their servers for external access to the db and that is good and usefull. But on the other hand I can not access the Database on my Server.
Unfortunately I do not have access to the Console output, but I get the Status Code:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

when I enter the Api domain.
When I try the Web API locally on my Desktop with the local Connection String, the API works properly. Moreover I can connect to the Database via the default php Script from IONOS itself:
https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/using-php-for-web-projects/connect-to-mysql-databases-using-php-code-examples/ (Last Access: 28.09.24)
Local Connection String:
"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=exampledb;username=root;password=MySecurePassword;"

Here is the Code which is located in the Program.cs file:
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));

    });
}
else
{
    if (builder.Environment.EnvironmentName.Equals("Production"))
    {
        connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Production");

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
           

        });
    }
}

Thank you for your Help,
FloFlo
